# Creating polygons from centroids in Python for an interactive map?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe where each record is a point. I am making an application using Flask and Python and would like to display an interactive map in HTML where the points would be transformed into a raster or into polygons from centroids. Each pixel would have an onclick event. I used geopandas simplify and dissolve and buffer (separately) to create polygons from the points with ok-looking results but then I can only display the map as a static image in HTML. I tried Bokeh but the best I can get is square points on a map which do not look good because I want them to be touching as a continuous structure but do not know the scale in advance so cannot set the right size of the point. 
Ultimately, I would like it to be like a grid in this tutorial (but they use polygons): https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson5-interactive-map-bokeh.html
[image]
Would anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a satisfactory solution to this. I check the distance between any two random points in the geopandas dataframe. They are all spaced evenly. Then I apply a buffer on all points using using half of the distance calculated in the previous step. Then, I apply the [envelope()](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.envelope) method on each point which results in a geodataframe of even polygons touching on the edges so it looks like a raster. I could not create a map from geopandas dataframe directly in Bokeh so I used Pandas-Bokeh library and it gave good results, including a hover method for each 'pixel'/ polygon.